# Linking libcurl issue

Tags: c++, gcc, ubuntu, g++

I am trying to compile a C++ project that requires libcurl on ubuntu.

I've installed the following package:

```
libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```

Running "pkg-config --libs curl" returns:

```
-lcurl
```

Running "curl-config --libs" returns:

```
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

This is my g++ build command line:

```
g++ -lboost_program_options -pthread -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl main.cpp
```

These are the errors that I am getting:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x374): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x416): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x434): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
main.cpp:(.text+0x442): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
main.cpp:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter order matters in g++ command, try:

```
g++ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lboost_program_options -pthread  -lcurl
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have ran into this issue before, but for some reason I was convinced that the order it was in was correct. I even went on to check on the g++ help page and it was: "Usage: g++ [options] file...". Anyways, thanks again.